# Правильно перенести данные из List в List

Tags: c#

Грубо говоря есть:

```
//_void по примеру собирает из базы child объекты
List<List<var>> example1 = _void(var);
List<List<var>> example2;
//Сменится на false когда функция _void вернет null (не осталось дочерних объектов)
while(true)
{
//Перебор с целью создать временное хранилище на 2 листе для цикла
foreach(List(var) list in example1)
{
   foreach(var obj in list)
   {
      example2.Add(_void(obj));
   }
}
example1 = example2;
example2.Clear();
}
```

И цикл уходит в вечность, от того что лист1 и лист2 отчищаются от последнего шага, от того не происходит foreach. Как поправить?

Comment: цикл уходит в вечность от того, что `while(true)`. Поправить - убрать `while`.

Comment: Это набросок от рабочего кода, что на другой машине. While сменится на false когда не останется дочерних объектов.

Comment: Если этот код уходит в вечность, то показывайте свою функцию _void (согласитесь, странное название для функции, которая что-то возвращает. чем вам foo не устроило? Или bar если foo мало?), потому что поведение этого кода может и зацикливаться и не зацикливаться... в зависимости от того, что напихано в функцию. Пока вопрос на закрытие, пока не будет mvce.

Comment: Имя типа `var`, имя метода `_void` - за  такие именования бить ногами. | `while (true) // сменится на false` - переменная меняется из другого потока?

Comment: Я просто привел набросок кода...
Полный код содержит функции из сторонней библиотеки, которые используются в методе _void.
Просто меня напрягает: Почему когда присваиваешь значение List2 к List1, получается когда очищаю List2 и очищается List1 ВОТ ВСЯ СУТЬ ВОПРОСА!
Код выше набросок что бы были видны условия!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Нет. Смотрите, у него `example1` и `example2` ссылаются в конце цикла на одно и то же. Причем - пустое. В `foreach` код больше не заходит. А крутится в `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
// example1 = example2;
example1.AddRange(example2);
```

Но так `example1` будет все время увеличиваться. Соответственно, внешний `foreach` будет состоять из все большего числа итераций.

```
example1.Clear();
example1.AddRange(example2);
```

Comment: Можно перед этим отчистить example1?

Comment: @Evok Наверное, можно. Тут мы переходим в область гаданий.